# Errors when installing AzSDK - Cannot convert the "System.Object[]"

Tags: powershell, azure

I am getting the following errors when installing **Secure DevOps Kit for Azure**/AzSDK with `Install-Module AzSDK -Scope CurrentUser`

> Install-Package : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
>   'InstalledModuleInfo'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of
>   type "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo".

Adding suggested `-AllowClobber` and `-Force` flags doesn't help.

PowerShell version - 5.1.14393.1944  (must be above 5.0 as per [docs](https://github.com/azsdk/azsdk-docs/tree/master/00a-Setup) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with cleanup of `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` folder.

Apparently then a new version of AzureRM module gets fully downloaded (vs updated) and there are no problems with installation od AzSDK.